# Problem with Uploadify 3.0

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flash, uploadify

I am trying to make the Uploadify 3.0 (Beta) work. As there is no any documentation on the uploadify website available, I'm having great difficulty. Therefore I will appreciate if someone can help me.

The problem I'm facing is that when I select file, the uploading process starts normally and the process bar completes and it says that the upload is completed (and process bar disappears, normally). Everything seems to behave as normal BUT the file does not upload to the folder.

I have made sure that the folder exists (eg. a folder named upload within the same directory to keep it simple).
Here is what I'm doing:

I have extracted all files in a folder and made the test.php file for the uploading. The content of the file are:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Uploadify scriptData Sample</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="uploadify.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.uploadify.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                        'swf' : 'uploadify.swf',
                        'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
                        'cancelImg' : 'uploadify-cancel.png',
                        'folder' : 'uploads',
                        'auto' : true   
                        });
    });
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <fieldset style="border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; padding: 8px; margin: 8px 0;">
        <legend><strong>Upload Files - scriptData Sample with Response</strong></legend>        
        <h2>Multiple File Auto Upload</h2>
        <p>Images Only</p>
        <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
    </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

I the uploadify.php is the default file in the download package which simply moves the file to the folder. 
However I have noticed that even if i remove the link of the uploady.php or uploadify.swf, it will not effect on it, and it will still say that the file is uploaded succesffully, so i think the problem is that the script never goes to the uploadify config settings in the javascript

```
($('#file_upload').uploadify({
)
```

which has the uploadify.php file which has code to move the file.

I have wasted many hours on this problem, if someone can help me, i will really appriciate it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use version 2.1.4? it has great documentation... no need to fight with it if you can use the version that is documented and works great. (I use it all the time.) (http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)

Answer (score 2):

Uploadify 3.0 (Beta) no longer supports the setting 'folder' : 'path'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                    'swf' : 'uploadify.swf',
                    'uploader' : 'uploadify.php',
                    'cancelImg' : 'uploadify-cancel.png',
                    'folder' : 'uploads',
                    'auto' : true   
                    });
});
```

you can hardcode the path of the upload directory in your uploadify.php script

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem, but I end up using another useful and editable API, Its name is "jQuery File Upload". and this can let you upload files to your site via Ajax.

You can give it a try, check out the website. http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

This API is friendly, so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error messages in the javascript console? Have you tried it in different browsers. Have you checked the permissions on the destination directory so the server-user can write to it? If it's a beta maybe  you should file a bug here http://www.uploadify.com/forums/discussions